# Why does my name not show up in messages

Tags: ios, bug

My contact name does not show up when I send a message, but my email address does. My contacts can't tell who messaging is from.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an address book entry for yourself which includes that email address?

Answer (score 1):

Let's check your settings and see what you have under Settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive. Make sure your "Start New Conversations From" setting is your phone number instead of an email address.

The existing threads with people will still use your email, but when you start a new thread, it will use your phone number properly.

Comment: I suspect that is the problem: the default send from address was changed to something that isn't in the OP's friends address books. You could also unregister the problematic address from iMessage altogether.